# Laravel: Property [email] does not exist on this collection instance

Tags: php, laravel

Hi I keep getting an error saying property [email] does not exist on this collection instance. What am I doing wrong? What is the correct way to retrieve the email address?

Here is my code in controller:

```
 public function runCommand(Request $request){

  $user = User::select("id", "email")->get();
  $signature = $request->input('signature');

  $command =  Artisan::call($signature, ['user' => $user->email]);


  return response($command);
}
```

Comment: You're selecting all users, not a single one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are selecting all users from the database. And a collection of users does not have a single property `email`. You should add a filter and use the `first()` function to get a single user object from the database.

Like so:

```
$user = User::where('id', 1)->select("id", "email")->first();
dd($user->email);
```

Answer (score 2):

`get()` method returns collection, use  `first()`.

```
$user = User::where('id', $id)->select("id", "email")->first();
```